# Getting undefined in JSON response

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am using the CodeIgniter shopping cart. I am fetching the all the add to cart information and I am getting the output in the alert(data) but I am not able to check the `o.qty`. I am getting undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Member_controller/primaryCartload",
          context: document.body,
          success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);

            if (data != 0) {
              console.log(data);
              alert(data);
              var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              $.each(obj, function(i, o) {
                  alert(o.qty);
                  if (o.qty != 0) {
                    $('#subtotal_details').html('Total cost:' + o.subtotal);
                    //alert('not empty');
                  });
              }
              else {
                //alert('empty')
                $('#totalDetails').html('0');
                $('#totalQty').html('Total items:0');
              }
            }
          });
      });
```

**Controller**

```
public function primaryCartload()
 {
  $output=[];
  $count = 0;

  foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items)
  {
   $count++;
   $output[] = array(
            'id' =>$items["id"],
            'qty' =>$items["qty"],
            'subtotal'=>$items["subtotal"],
            'removebtn'=>$items["rowid"],
            'cart_total'=>$this->cart->total()
            );
  }
  $outputStore['outputStore']=$output;
  if($count == 0)
  {
   $outputStore ['outputStore']= 0;
  }
 echo json_encode($outputStore);
 exit();
}
```

I am getting the output in the alert(data)

```
{"outputStore":[{"id":"1","qty":1,"subtotal":5000,"removebtn":"c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b","cart_total":6000},{"id":"2","qty":1,"subtotal":1000,"removebtn":"c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c","cart_total":6000}]}
```

but when I am accessing the o.qty then I am getting `undefined`

Comment: Try replacing o.qty != 0 with typeof o.qty == "number"

Comment: try ```console.log( typeof(o) );``` before alert( . This is how you will know weather ```o``` is an object or not .

Comment: Also, I think your reference is wrong, based on your output shouldn't it be, o["outputStore"][index]["qty"] ?

Comment: @Tamim, I am getting  me undefined. I tried  alert(console.log( typeof(o) ));

Comment: try ```alert(typeof(o))```

Comment: @Tamim, I got object in alert

Comment: In your php try inserting" echo print_r($items, true);" after $count++, this should dump the content into the console.

Comment: @SPlatten, I am getting my output echo print_r($items, true); it like same as in alert

Comment: If this is how you displayed in your post then the reference is wrong and should be as I suggested using "outputStore" and the index of the item you want to extract.

Comment: I have post an answer, please check

Comment: @SPlatten, Can you help more about where I am wrong?

Comment: I think the answer posted by Tasmin is closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the array from data object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Member_controller/primaryCartload",
          context: document.body,
          success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);

            if (data != 0) {
              console.log(data);
              alert(data);
              var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              $.each(obj["outputStore"], function(i, o) {
                  alert(o.qty);
                  if (o.qty != 0) {
                    $('#subtotal_details').html('Total cost:' + o.subtotal);
                    //alert('not empty');
                  });
              }
              else {
                //alert('empty')
                $('#totalDetails').html('0');
                $('#totalQty').html('Total items:0');
              }
            }
          });
      });
```

Comment: I am getting the error in console  JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: ```JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data``` That means something wrong with  returned data from backend.

Comment: If the data shown in the original post is already an object then you don't need to call JSON.parse(data), just remove that and iterate through data["outputStore"]

Comment: Give me some time to check